# Is it possible to use a (different) password for an account over Remote Desktop than locally?

Tags: windows-8.1, security, remote-desktop, passwords

I have an account that I want to be password-less locally, but I obviously don't want that to be the case remotely.

Is there any way to make a password specifically only for Remote Desktop?

Comment: You set the default account which has a password to automatically log into that account when the computer is restarted, which leaves a password that exists, when you want to remotely access it.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don't want the account to have a password at all; I'm not asking about automatic login.

Comment: In that case, the answer to your question is a four words, "no that's not possible".

Comment: @Ramhound: Post it as an answer!